# Is it possible to reallocate NSF funds from the graduating PhD student to support the postdoc?

Tags: postdocs, funding, nsf

An NSF grant budget includes funding for two PhD students, with one student graduating soon and transitioning to a postdoc position within the group. Is it possible to reallocate funds from the graduating PhD student to support the postdoc for a few months? If so, would this change to the budget allocation require approval from NSF?

Comment: You should contact the grant point person at NSF in your field and ask directly.

Comment: You are asking for technicalities involving a contract, i.e. legal advices specific to a certain countries. Free legal advices from people in the internet may potentially bring you enormous benefits, in their absolute value.

Comment: @EarlGrey You meant to say "malefits", I assume.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs That's why Earl Grey mentioned the absolute value.

Comment: The authority to make such a budget change belongs to the NSF. In some cases, the NSF delegates some of this authority to the institution that receives the grant. I don't know whether your case is covered by such a delegation. I'd guess it's not, and it might vary from one grantee to another.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I realized, but I thought it might help some to see the misdirection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to ask this question to NSF. Right now, you are risking an answer by a chatbot here that might give you unfounded legal advice.

Comment: As an AI, I am not qualified to give a formal answer, but [fill as required]